# C# - Save a Multi-Line Textbox to a text file

Tags: c#, list, multiline, savefiledialog

I am creating a small app for personal use that allows me to clean my lists of objects.  I am using a variety of filters to get a finalized list in a multiline text box.  When i am finished, I use the following code to copy to the textbox to the clipboard.

```
    #region COPY BUTTON
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox_ListDestination.Text);
    }
    #endregion
```

What i would like to do now is add another button that allows me to save this same text to a .txt file using the SaveFileDialog.  Can anyone help me with this?  I am assuming I would use Streaming of some type, but I am out of my element here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
File.WriteAllText (TargetFilePath, textBox_ListDestination.Text);
```

For more information including sample code see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx).

If you want to obtain `TargetFilePath` via a `SaveFileDialog` see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).

UPDATE

Sample code using `SaveFileDialog`:

```
 if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     File.WriteAllText (saveFileDialog1.FileName, textBox_ListDestination.Text);
 }
```

Comment: So would the TargetFilePath be saveFileDialog1?  It is giving me the red squiggly when i try to use "File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1, textBox_ListDestination.Text);"

Comment: @Jeagr no... have you followed the second link which shows sample code on how to use SaveFileDialog ?

Comment: Yes, but I am new at this and MSDN takes some getting used to.  At the bottom of the page, there is a sample which i used, but the text that goes here"// Code to write the stream goes here." is problematic...  I used "File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1, textBox_ListDestination.Text);" but it didnt work.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that part out, but it is giving me two errors...1 = no admin priveldges...must save in documents folder.  And 2 = error, file is in use by another process...but its a new file.  Here is a pic of the error:  http://screencast.com/t/f6YGaQa8Pb9

Comment: @Jeagr can't help you with that... either you chose a location where you don't have permission to create/write a file OR something is weird with your machine...

Comment: @Jeagr that's a whole new question... and the screenshot itself is not enough to answer that... sorry...